# JS display of objects and the property of each

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

So neophyte trying to understand early steps of Javascript. I'm attempting to learn about arrays of objects and how to display the object and its property. The example is to show the color of fruit:

```
var fruitColor = {'apples':'red', 'bananas':'yellow', 'grapes':'purple'};


//answer would be string and then the properties...
//"Color of fruit: apples - red, bananas - yellow, grapes - purple"
```

Comment: Object.keys and basic loops should get you started.  If you don't like object.keys, you can also use a `for in loop`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys  and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: Thanks for this reference link...very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like :

```
var fruitColor = {'apples':'red', 
                  'bananas':'yellow', 
                  'grapes':'purple'
                  };
var sentence="Color of fruit: ";
for(var fruit in fruitColor){
    sentence+= fruit + " - " + fruitColor[fruit] + ", ";
}
sentence=sentence.substring(0, sentence.length - 2); 
// remove the last ','
```

Look at the `for...in` loop

https://jsfiddle.net/n0z13ge6/